# Number theory about Big O

Tags: number-theory

$\frac{-2}{log2} + \int_{2}^{x} {1\over log^2 t}dt = O({1\over log^2 x})$
Is it true?

I want to prove that
$li(x)={x\over logx}+O({x\over log^2x})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \int_{2}^{x} {1\over log^2 t}dt
=\Omega(\frac{x}{\log^2(x)})
$
so the $O(\frac1{\log^2(x)})$
is false.

Comment: Thanks, and would you give a hint for li(x)=xlogx+O(xlog2x)